# Whatsapp not loading images nad not creating back up on my htc explorer (Cyanogen mod 11 CR4)

Tags: cyanogenmod, whatsapp-messenger, htc-explorer

I have installed Cyanogen mod11 CR4 on my htc explorer.
Also I have increased my internal memory via partitioning the sd card and merging it with internal memory.

When I installed Whatsapp. It is not creating its folders (of conversations, images, videos). Due to this, I cannot download or upload images. Also it is not allowing to back up conversation.

Can anyone help me in this regard?
Thank you.